# Airflow connection name with "-" (hyphen) using Environment variable is not working

Tags: airflow

We have an airflow HTTP connection by name "**service-1-con**".
This is working fine when we have used airflow CLI to manage the connections.

Now the same is not working when specified using `env` variable **AIRFLOW_CONN_SERVICE-1-CON**.
There are other HTTP connections using `env` variables which work. Only this one is not working.
We suspect this could be due to the hyphen in the name. But it works when managed through UI and airflow CLI.

Can somebody advise what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

Here's how you can debug:

```py
import os
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

conn_id = 'service-1-con'
env_var = f'AIRFLOW_CONN_{conn_id}'.upper()
os.environ[env_var] = 'ssh://hello:mypassword@'

conn = BaseHook.get_connection(conn_id)
print(conn.get_uri())
```

[Here is the code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f6ba8b5757c6866d614459d32745049751844021/airflow/secrets/environment_variables.py#L33-L35) where the connections are retrieved from env vars.